# Class 'Laravel\Ui\UiCommand' not found when install argon dashboard in laravel 8

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8, argon

When i trird to install [argon](https://argon-dashboard-laravel.creative-tim.com/docs/getting-started/installation.html) dashboard i got the below errors when i run this command : `composer require laravel-frontend-presets/argon` inside my project .

```
   Error

  Class 'Laravel\Ui\UiCommand' not found

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\eloquent\vendor\laravel-frontend-presets\argon\src\ArgonPresetServiceProvider.php:19
     15▕      * @return void
     16▕      */
     17▕     public function boot()
     18▕     {
  ➜  19▕         UiCommand::macro('argon', function ($command) {
     20▕             ArgonPreset::install();
     21▕
     22▕             $command->info('Argon scaffolding installed successfully.');
     23▕         });

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\eloquent\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      LaravelFrontendPresets\ArgonPreset\ArgonPresetServiceProvider::boot()

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\eloquent\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:40
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and i fixed it by running

`composer require laravel/ui`

before doing

`composer dump-autoload`.